# Sort output from csv files by date python

Tags: python, csv

i have a lot of csv files with date, row[0] = is date in format: year-month-date, and i have output from this files.

```
        for row in reader:
            out = row[0], row[2] + "/" + row[3], row[5]
            print(out)
```

out example:

```
('2018-07-21', 'info1', 'info2')
('2018-03-19', 'info1', 'info2')
('2018-07-14', 'info1', 'info2')
('2018-05-16', 'info1', 'info2')
('2018-01-27', 'info1', 'info2')
```

how i can sort this output by date, or add this rows to list and sort in list, but i have output from files in tuple. thank you for help

Comment: Your sample output is suspect, since it contains no '/' characters in the second column

Comment: hello, it is not issue, i asking about column1, how to sort output?

Comment: What have *you* tried? SO is not a free coding service

Comment: if you have no propositions just get lost!

Comment: I think the point is that you should have been able to find this answer (as graciously posted for you by Martin Stone below) for yourself with the same or less effort than posting this question.

Comment: you can lost too, if you dont have any additional comments about my question, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your tuples directly:

```
csvinfo = [
    ('2018-07-21', 'info1', 'info2'),
    ('2018-03-19', 'info1', 'info2'),
    ('2018-07-14', 'info1', 'info2'),
    ('2018-05-16', 'info1', 'info2'),
    ('2018-01-27', 'info1', 'info2')]

print(sorted(csvinfo))
```

See [Python Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: This will probably do the trick, but will also sort on subsequent elements when there are duplicate values in the first column. If it is important to preserve the original order in the event of duplicate dates, then add `key=lambda row: row[0]`, or import operator and do `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`. This will sort *only* on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

first you convert the date from string to date with datetime
and then sort the dates, usually with lists it works well.

Comment: These dates don't even need to be converted, since they are already in `yyyy-mm-dd` form, so will sort lexically just as they are.